# Controlling height when scaling window

Tags: css, scaling

I'm working on a webpage, where I'm getting stuck right now.

If you take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrnAg/) you will probably get the idea of how my design works. I have a div table, and on top of that I have another table as overlay, creating the effect of the div floating above the rest. This is done with absolute position, and as such works as intended. But, I always want to have it beautiful when scaling to smaller screens, and my minimum is `640px`, which I try to make every webpage I make, work on.

But, if you now take a look at my JSFiddle, you should pretty much see how it should look like when as intended. Besides missing some fonts, colors etc. Buy besides that, as intended. Now, if you try to change the .content div to:

```
.content {
     max-width:640px;
}
```

Instead of the `960px` it is now, this should make the box smaller, as it would if you had a smaller screen, or scaled your window. But, as you see, the absolute position overlay do not extent with the rest, and is left a bit short.

I've tried multiple things with max-height, min-height etc., but nothing really worked. So I was hoping someone could give me a hint of some sort to how I could create this, with the div overlay scaling with the rest.

Hope you understand what I mean :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your title I assume you want to look into media queries
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the word in your overlay 'hjemmeside' is too long, and causing the div to overflow. You can add `html { word-break:break-all; }` to fix this issue. See [demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/5e908aa10f35cf650eb73f9cbddcb2bf) here.